# Open Source UML eclipse plug-in with code generation

Tags: java, code-generation, uml

I am looking for an Open Source UML eclipse plug-in that allow me to add my defined stereotypes which map to a defined annotations when generating code.

Anyone have worked with a plug-in that provide these capabilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No open source tool can generate annotation in your java code using UML stereotypes. The only database profile I know generating EJB3 annotation in your java code is not open source and is an Omondo corp technology.

One friend of mine refused to pay the licence and have generated his code using EclipseUML2 plugin and then manually added annotation using Dali another Eclipse plugin. 
I mean that he has used EclipseUML2 plugin and then has added dali annotation for the code. It was really painful and now that the EclipseUML2 plugin has not been updated to the latest Helios build he is totally stuck in his project.

I have myself paid for the licence (e.g; got good a deal for only 990€ and certainly not the huge amount they first asked for :-) and must admit my life is easy and my project rapidly done. I can now spend more time playing golf than staying late in the office because I prefer my boss pay the tool I need than saving money on software and making my life a nightmare !!